# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'context of GenericRepository<Incident>.GenericRepository(dbContext)

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, repository-pattern

I am getting this error message which when trying to inherit from my GenericRepository. The error says I need to also provide a context but I am not sure how?

```
//IncidentRepository 
public class IncidentRepository : GenericRepository<Incident>

//Generic Repository (to inherit from)
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
internal db_SLee_FYPContext context;
internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

public GenericRepository(db_SLee_FYPContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
}
```

EDIT:

Just to check I've grasped this?

```
  public class IncidentRepository: GenericRepository<Incident>
  {

    public IncidentRepository(db_SLee_FYPContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    //Then in my genric repository
    public GenericRepository()
    {

    }
```

Comment: I should only need a default constructor in my Incident Repository but I still get this error.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The error tells you that you don't call an appropriate base constructor. The constructor in the derived class ...

```
public IncidentRepository(db_SLee_FYPContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
}
```

... is in fact doing this:

```
public IncidentRepository(db_SLee_FYPContext context)
    : base()
{
    this.context = context;
}
```

But there is no parameterless base constructor.

You should fix this by calling the matching base constructor:

```
public IncidentRepository(db_SLee_FYPContext context)
    : base(context)
{ }
```

In C# 6 you get this message if there is only one constructor in the base type, so it gives you the best possible hint which argument in the base constructor is missing. In C# 5 the message would simply be

> GenericRepository does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: Well explained.

Comment: Nice answer; I wish the error message (seen in the title of this question) used the word "constructor", as the source of issue (and fix) would be more obvious

Comment: @TheRedPea Yes! Or even "the implicitly invoked closest-matching base constructor". Or a link to this answer :-)

Comment: i have applied but, still error in my code

Comment: Shouldn't the 'dbSet' be public so it could be used in the 'IncidentRepository'?

Comment: No, it should even be `protected`; `internal` is way too open. But you shouldn't ask me.