# Inheritance from generic class with abstract property

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm trying to have a class inherit from an abstract class with a generic property in it. I think I'm missing something real important. The only way I can  get rid of this error is getting rid of the constructor in the base class. But if I do that then my class would lack of purpose.

**Error**

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'propA'...

**Base Class**

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T:class
{
    public string propA{ get; set; }
    public int propB{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> propC { get; set; }

    public BaseClass(string propA, int propB, IEnumerable<T> propC)
    {
        this.propA = propA;
        this.propB = spropB; 
        this.propC = propC;
    }

    public abstract IEnumerable<T> Method1();

    public abstract string Method2();

    public abstract void Method3();
}
```

**Derived Class**

```
public class DerivedClass: BaseClass<SomeClass> 
{
    public override IEnumerable<SomeClass> Method1()
    {
        //Code Here
    }

    public override string GetDefaultSortField()
    {
         //Code Here
    }

    public override void SetSortParams()
    {
         //Code Here
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe instead of abstract base class you should use interface (e.g. `IBaseClass<T>`). Then you can design constructors based on your needs.

Comment: This has nothing to do with abstract classes or generics - it's simply a matter of a default constructor in a derived class calling a constructor in the base class passing no arguments. Your base class could be concrete and non-generic and you'd still have the same problem. What do you want to happen if you call `new DerivedClass()`? Do you expect the three-parameter constructor in `BaseClass` to be called, and if so, what arguments do you expect to be passed to it?

Comment: With VS2015 F10 also helps you create that derived constructor automatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'context of GenericRepository<Incident>.GenericRepository(dbContext)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701210/there-is-no-argument-given-that-corresponds-to-the-required-formal-parameter-co)

Comment: @JonSkeet you were right. I missed the constructor in the DerivedClass. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have an explicit constructor in your derived class, so it 'inherits' the constructor of the base class.  But the base class constructor has a parameter that uses a generic type T, which is not defined in the derived class.  If you add a constructor explicitly to the derived class, it should be fine.
I mean like this:

```
    public DerivedClass(string propA, int propB, IEnumerable<SomeClass> propC)
        : base(propA, propB, propC)
    {
    }
```

Note that this way the `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` becomes `IEnumerable<T>` in the base class, as the generic type parameter T is bound to `SomeClass` in `DerivedClass`.

Answer (score 2):

You've missed the `constructor` in the `DerivedClass`. But since the default constructor in the base class contains three parameters you need to call the matching base constructor. So add this constructor to the `DerivedClass` and it will solve your issue:

```
public DerivedClass(string propA, int propB, IEnumerable<SomeClass> propC) 
      : base(propA, propB, propC)
{
}
```